# different ways of assigning onclick events dojo

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

The second approach, where I hardcode the input id's and connect them to onclick events works properly.

But, when I use the first approach, it doesn't work. 
The code executes in this manner.

```
      select1.on('change',function(evt) {
           requiredFunction(select8.id);//select9 is not present (so I changed loop end                                    value from inputs.length -1 to inputs.length -2 )
      }
```

Am I missing some event handling principles in dojo?

Approach1:

```
        function assignOnClickEvents(table) {
            var inputs = document.getElementById(table).getElementsByClassName('classname');
            for (var i = 0; i < (inputs.length - 1); i++) {                    
                dijit.byId(inputs[i].id).on('change', function (evt) {
                    requiredFunction(inputs[i+1].id);
                });
            }
        }
```

Approach2:

```
        function assignOnClickEvents() {                

            var select1 = dijit.byId('select1');
            var select2 = dijit.byId('select2');
            var select3 = dijit.byId('select3');
            var select4 = dijit.byId('select4');
            var select5 = dijit.byId('select5');
            var select6 = dijit.byId('select6');
            var select7 = dijit.byId('select7');                
            var select8 = dijit.byId('select8');
            var select9 = dijit.byId('select9');
            select1.on('change', function (evt) {
                requiredFunction('select2');
            });
            select2.on('change', function (evt) {
                requiredFunction('select3');
            });
            select3.on('change', function (evt) {
                requiredFunction('select4');
            });
            select4.on('change', function (evt) {
                requiredFunction('select5');
            });                
            select5.on('change', function (evt) {
                requiredFunction('select6');
            });
            select6.on('change', function (evt) {
                requiredFunction('select7');
            });
            select7.on('change', function (evt) {
                requiredFunction('select8');
            });
            select8.on('change', function (evt) {
                requiredFunction('select9');
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing DOM node IDs and Dijit IDs. This could be a possible reason why your code isn't working.
To fix this, you could try the following approach:

```js
var inputs = dijit.findWidgets(table); // Returns widgets, not DOM nodes
for(var i = 0;i < inputs.length - 1;i++) {
    inputs[i].on('change', function(evt) {
        // Remind: this returns the widget ID, not the DOM ID
        requiredFunction(inputs[i+1].id);
    });
}
```

In dojo there is a difference between widgets and DOM nodes. So using DOM functions (to retrieve a DOM node by ID or by classname) will not always work. They could work, but that's not always the fact.

Comment: I just checked in Developer Tools that dijit.byId(document.getElementById('tablenameFromParameter').getElementsByClassN‌​ame('classname')[i].id) returns [Widget dijit.form.Select, accountNameSelectForExcel(AC)], which is a widget. While, dijit.findWidgets('tablenameFromParameter') returns nothing. Though, I m returning DOM Nodes, I m getting the dijit Widget by using dijit.byId(DOMNode.id)

Answer (score 0):

You can also call your function `requiredFunction()` as follow :

```
<input data-dojo-attach-event="onChange:requiredFunction"></input>
```

This will reduce your time of looping and work similar as you want.

All the best.